# Magento Themes and Templates

Tags: php, magento-1.5, magento

I've a real serious issue.

I've started developing in Magento just last month, and I committed a mistake by not follwoing Magento approach for theming and template's, and instead I modified files in base directory. You might say that you used the wrong approach, I know that I've screwed up. but, I had no time to go through heavy tutorials. so, I used quick approach and I directly modified templated  at {which I now understand was worst thing to do :( } -

**app/design/frontend//base/default**

and added my css and js etc at : 
** skin/frontend/base/default **

I have heavily customized the design. Now, I have  a real real big issue, i need to create a mobile compitable site. I followed these two links
[Design Exception](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/) and 
[enter link description here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-mobilize-your-magento-site-for-iphone-android-mobile-commerce/)

now the problem is, since I've modified the **.phtml** files in **base** the changes are not reflected.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the base files you modified/added into a freshly-named new directory for your theme, then  about replacing the base files with the defaults.

Comment: well, I understand the duplicating part: so i renamed current **base** directory to **baseOLD** and copied a fresh base from magento to **app/design/frontend/**, so, now I have three directory under **app/design/frontend/** : _base_, _baseOLD_ and _default_  and same under **skin/frontend/** directory. But, I do not understand _then about replacing the base files with the defaults_, Please let me know what do you want me to do. thanks in advance.

Comment: You've done exactly what I meant - now you just have to set Magento to read from your new theme directories in System --> Configuration --> Design --> Themes. Once that's done, Magento will 'fall back' onto the base files if anything is missing from your customized theme - the idea is, that you only have files you've MODIFIED from the base files in your 'baseOLD' directory. Any files that you haven't changed will be missing and Magento will call the originals from the Base directory. I've probably made this sound confusing, but it really isn't.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer. I've been able to run the site both on web and on mobile. one more question. I've modified files in different directories in **template** as well as **layout**, now suppose I've made a layout change and I want those changes to appear in both, mobile and web version, i.e. **header & footer** links, etc. so where those **template** & **layout** files should be, in **baseOLD** or in **base**???

Comment: baseOLD. The rule with Magento theming is that you never directly modify the base files. You duplicate files you want to modify into a new directory, THEN make your changes to leave the fall-back architecture unchanged. This is also a means of upgrade-proofing your themes, since the base files may be overwritten with updates.

Comment: What's your name? thank you for your answer. Now one more question, I modified my home page and loaded advanced search page as home page for web view. now when I open the site on mobile. it's home page breadcrumb says Home Page/ Catalog Advanced Search. I've now moved all files from modified base to  ** frontend/my-theme/default/**, removed **baseOLD**, now I want in case of mobile all (those not in **iphone** directory) files to be picked from **frontend/base/default** and in all other cases from **frontend/my-theme/default/**. is it possible, if yes, what files I've to change ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that, but I know you need to use the "Add Exceptions" buttons to specify that mobile user agents are sent the base files under System --> Configuration --> Design.